# Error #1215 al crear una referencia foránea en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Esta es la consulta SQL que me genera el error:

```
ALTER TABLE `productos` 
ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CATEGORIA`) REFERENCES `categorias`(`ID`) ON 
DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
> #1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint

[image: Captura de pantalla del listado de tablas]

[image: Captura de pantalla de la definición de la tabla productos]
[image: Captura de pantalla de la definición de la tabla categorias]

Comment: Buenas. No se si tendrá que ver pero la longitud del campo ID_CATEGORIA en la tabla productos, no coincide con la del campo ID en la tabla Categorias. Hasta donde se no debería de afectar pero sería algo que probaría a cambiar seguro para ver si se soluciona. Ayudaría también que exportaras las tablas y nos colgaras las consultas de creación de las tablas para que pudiéramos hacer pruebas con la estructura exacta que tienes. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para ello te sugiero que compartas la definición de las tablas haciendo uso de `SHOW CREATE TABLE productos` y  `SHOW CREATE TABLE categorias`.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no compartes la definición de las tablas, es más que probable que no estés cumpliendo los requisitos necesarios para crear claves foráneas: [que las referencias sean índices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

En castellano:

> MySQL requiere índices en claves foráneas y claves referenciadas para que las comprobaciones de claves foráneas puedan ser rápidas y no requieran un escaneo de tabla.

Para corregirlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE productos
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    ADD INDEX (ID_CATEGORIA)

ALTER TABLE categorias
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

Tras lo cual ya podrás crear la relación:

```
ALTER TABLE productos
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES categorias(ID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Puedes ver el correcto funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ngpHUX3GyMnZj9YFvrEAdW/0